# How to analyze work item history from Azure DevOps in Power BI?

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, dax, azure-boards

I'm currently trying to create extensive Power BI report for Azure DevOps work items. I got direct access with SQL to analytics tables and views. I have already checked the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/overview?view=azure-devops), but most of the sample reports for historical data pretty much refers to **WorkItemSnapshot** table.

I also did some experiments with **WorkItemSnapshot** but that would force me to go with daily level reporting and I would be also interested of weekly or sprint level history. Also even with direct SQL call and some WHERE limitations it was really slow for longer periods (we got lot of stuff on db). I thought that since that table is anyway some sort of CROSSJOIN between dates and **WorkItemRevision** table, probably I could directly fetch the full table on use some DAX magic to achieve much more performant and flexible end result. Only thing is that I don't have enough of that magic and that is why I'm here.

Some measures I'm looking for:

- Total efforts: daily, weekly, sprint, PI
- Done efforts: daily, weekly, sprint, PI
- Items moved out of sprint during sprint
- Items moved to the sprint during sprint

To start with total efforts we would need **sum of effort** for **last revision** of **each work item** in current filter context, say single date. Probably we haven't modified work item on that date so we would need to fetch last revision before that date.

Here is simplified example of **WorkItemRevision** data for someone who is not familiar with [Azure DevOps datamodel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/data-model-analytics-service?view=azure-devops):

[image: Data example]

Hopefully you could throw in at least some comments which direction I should look for.

Comment: does the diagram in this screenshot help?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-dataset?view=azure-devops#data-relationships

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That won't really help. Actually I'm already using that model. On same page Microsoft is referring to snapshot table for historical data and that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. It is too SQL intensive to fetch that snapshot view when you have long history and a lot of work items.

Comment: In a similar vein, I'm trying to query all tickets between 2 given states (by checking for instance, all tickets that went from New to Approved, etc.) and tally up how many days it took for the average ticket. I've been able to query a ticket's full revision history, based on a given URL (https://dev.azure.com/<company-name>/_apis/wit/workItems/<work-item-ID>/revisions). So I was using a C# program to do mass querying with caching the tickets. But now I need to use Power Bi and am in the same boat.

Comment: I had this same question in Power BI community forum but no luck there either. It starts to look like we need to go with that WorkItemSnapshot table. My plan is to add lot of calculated columns like "IsCurrentSprint", "MovedInSprint", "MovedOutOfSprint" with comparing current to next or previous revision of same item.